# Charts not rendering properly

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm currently working on a dashboard project based on JSONP data from a SQL Server warehouse.
I've managed to configure Kendo datasources to read JSONP correctly and have confirmed the chart objects and tabstrip in my dashboard each render correctly with the correct data if all the other objects are removed, but when I combine multiple charts on screen, at best I get 3-4 charts displaying, and these display different values from one refresh to the next. 
My knowledge of JQuery is definitely beginner, having come from traditional BI desktop apps rather than a development background so I'm sure I've missed something simple, but I've been through numerous examples and forum threads to no avail.
Incidentally, I can force the tabstrip and first chart to display by wrapping them with $(function() {}); but if I wrap the other charts, none of them appear and if I wrap all the charts in one, I get the same results.
I've included my code below, thanks in advance.

Andy.

JS

```
var dscTop1Stats = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: {
        cache: false,
        url: "http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetTop1SourceStatsByUserData",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        jsonpCallback: "JsonPCallBack"
    }
}
});


var dscTop2Stats = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: {
        cache: false,
        url: "http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetTop2SourceStatsByUserData",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        jsonpCallback: "JsonPCallBack"
    }
}
});


var dscTop3Stats = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: {
        cache: false,
        url: "http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetTop3SourceStatsByUserData",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        jsonpCallback: "JsonPCallBack"
    }
}
});


var dscTop1StatsTrend = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: {
        cache: false,
        url: "http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetTop1SourceStatsTrendByUserData",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        jsonpCallback: "JsonPCallBack"
    }
}
});


var dscTop2StatsTrend = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: {
        cache: false,
        url: "http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetTop2SourceStatsTrendByUserData",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        jsonpCallback: "JsonPCallBack"
    }
}
});


var dscTop3StatsTrend = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: {
        cache: false,
        url: "http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetTop3SourceStatsTrendByUserData",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        jsonpCallback: "JsonPCallBack"
    }
}
});


var dscTop10Sources = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: {
        cache: false,
        url: "http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetRankingBySourcesData",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        jsonpCallback: "JsonPCallBack"
    }
}
});


$(function() {
$("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
    contentUrls: [
        "Sources.html",
        "Source Types.html",
        "Keyword Analysis.html",
        "Trend Analysis.html"
    ],
    animation: {
        close: {
            duration: 1000,
            effects: "fadeOut"
        },
        open: {
            duration: 500,
            effects: "fadeIn"
        }
    }
});
$("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
    animation: { open: { effects: "fadeIn" } },
    contentUrls: [
        '../../Sources.html',
        '../../Source Types.html',
        '../../Keyword Analysis.html',
        '../../Trend Analysis.html'
    ]
});

$("#chartSummary").kendoChart({
    dataSource: dscTop10Sources,
    legend: {
        position: "left"
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        labels: {
            template: "#= category # - #= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage)#",
            position: "outsideEnd",
            visible: true,
            background: "transparent"
        }
    },
    series:
    [{
        type: "column",
        field: "SearchStoriesCount",
        name: "Searched Stories"
    }],
    categoryAxis: {
        field: "Name",
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            font: "10px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",
            padding: { top: 0 }
        },
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: true
        }
    },
    valueAxis: {
        labels: {
            format: "N0"
        },
        majorUnit: 300,
        line: {
            visible: false
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        template: "#= category # - #= value #"
    }
});

$("#chartTop1").kendoChart({
    dataSource: dscTop1Stats,
    title: {
        text: "# Times stories searched in 31 days"
    },
    legend: {
        visible: false
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "bar"
    },
    series:
    [{
        field: "StoriesSearched",
        name: "Stories Searched"
    }],
    seriesColors: ["#AF99D7"],
    chartArea: {
        margin: {
            left: -3
        },
        background: ""
    },
    categoryAxis: {
        field: "AuthorName",
        labels: {
            rotation: -0,
            visible: false
        },
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: false
        }
    },
    valueAxis: {
        labels: {
            format: "N0"
        },
        majorUnit: 2000,
        line: {
            visible: false
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        format: "N0"
    }
});

    $("#chartTop2").kendoChart({
        dataSource: dscTop2Stats,
        title: {
            text: "# Times stories searched in 31 days"
        },
        legend: {
            visible: false
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: "bar"
        },
        series:
        [{
            field: "StoriesSearched",
            name: "Stories Searched"
        }],
        seriesColors: ["#AF99D7"],
        chartArea: {
            margin: {
                left: -3
            },
            background: ""
        },
        categoryAxis: {
            field: "AuthorName",
            labels: {
                rotation: -0,
                visible: false
            },
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        valueAxis: {
            labels: {
                format: "N0"
            },
            majorUnit: 2000,
            line: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            format: "N0"
        }
    });

    $("#chartTop3").kendoChart({
        dataSource: dscTop3Stats,
        title: {
            text: "# Times stories searched in 31 days"
        },
        legend: {
            visible: false
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: "bar"
        },
        series:
        [{
            field: "StoriesSearched",
            name: "Stories Searched"
        }],
        seriesColors: ["#AF99D7"],
        chartArea: {
            margin: {
                left: -3
            },
            background: ""
        },
        categoryAxis: {
            field: "AuthorName",
            labels: {
                rotation: -0,
                visible: false
            },
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        valueAxis: {
            labels: {
                format: "N0"
            },
            majorUnit: 2000,
            line: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            format: "N0"
        }
    });

    $("#areaTop1").kendoSparkline({
        title: {
            text: "31 Day Trend"
        },
        dataSource: dscTop1StatsTrend,
        series: [{
            type: "line",
            field: "StoriesSearched",
            name: "Relevant Stories",
            width: 2,
        }],
        seriesColors: ["#6B5593"],
        chartArea: {
            width: 350,
            height: 80,
            background: ""
        },
        categoryAxis: {
            field: "Date"
        }
    });

    $("#areaTop2").kendoSparkline({
        title: {
            text: "31 Day Trend"
        },
        dataSource: dscTop2StatsTrend,
        series: [{
            type: "line",
            field: "StoriesSearched",
            name: "Relevant Stories",
            width: 2,
        }],
        seriesColors: ["#6B5593"],
        chartArea: {
            width: 350,
            height: 80,
            background: ""
        },
        categoryAxis: {
            field: "Date"
        }
    });

    $("#areaTop3").kendoSparkline({
        title: {
            text: "31 Day Trend"
        },
        dataSource: dscTop3StatsTrend,
        series: [{
            type: "line",
            field: "StoriesSearched",
            name: "Relevant Stories",
            width: 2,
        }],
        seriesColors: ["#6B5593"],
        chartArea: {
            width: 350,
            height: 80,
            background: ""
        },
        categoryAxis: {
            field: "Date"
        }
    });
});

$.getJON("http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetTop1SourceStatsByUserData?callback=?", function (top1Stats) {
    $.each(top1Stats, function (i, item) {
        var content = '<p class="title_text">' + item.AuthorName + '</p>';
        $(content).appendTo("#Top1Author");
    });
});

$.getJSON("http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetTop1SourceStatsByUserData?callback=?", function (top1Stats) {
    $.each(top1Stats, function (i, item) {
        var content = '<p class="tag_text">' + item.Tags + '</p>';
        $(content).appendTo("#Top1Tags");
    });
});

$.getJSON("http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetTop1SourceStatsByUserData?callback=?", function (top1Stats) {
    $.each(top1Stats, function (i, item) {
        var content = '<p class="title_text">' + item.PercentUserContent + '% / ' + item.PercentTotalContent + '%</p>';
        $(content).appendTo("#Top1UservsTotal");
    });
});


$.getJSON("http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetTop2SourceStatsByUserData?callback=?", function (top2Stats) {
    $.each(top2Stats, function (i, item) {
        var content = '<p class="title_text">' + item.AuthorName + '</p>';
        $(content).appendTo("#Top2Author");
    });
});

$.getJSON("http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetTop2SourceStatsByUserData?callback=?", function (top2Stats) {
    $.each(top2Stats, function (i, item) {
        var content = '<p class="tag_text">' + item.Tags + '</p>';
        $(content).appendTo("#Top2Tags");
    });
});

$.getJSON("http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetTop2SourceStatsByUserData?callback=?", function (top2Stats) {
    $.each(top2Stats, function (i, item) {
        var content = '<p class="title_text">' + item.PercentUserContent + '% / ' + item.PercentTotalContent + '%</p>';
        $(content).appendTo("#Top2UservsTotal");
    });
});


$.getJSON("http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetTop3SourceStatsByUserData?callback=?", function (top3Stats) {
    $.each(top3Stats, function (i, item) {
        var content = '<p class="title_text">' + item.AuthorName + '</p>';
        $(content).appendTo("#Top3Author");
    });
});

$.getJSON("http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetTop3SourceStatsByUserData?callback=?", function (top3Stats) {
    $.each(top3Stats, function (i, item) {
        var content = '<p class="tag_text">' + item.Tags + '</p>';
        $(content).appendTo("#Top3Tags");
    });
});

$.getJSON("http://localhost:52387/Dash/GetTop3SourceStatsByUserData?callback=?", function (top3Stats) {
    $.each(top3Stats, function (i, item) {
        var content = '<p class="title_text">' + item.PercentUserContent + '% / ' + item.PercentTotalContent + '%</p>';
        $(content).appendTo("#Top3UservsTotal");
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<section class="well content-wrapper">
    <div class="main_content">
        <div class="frame_tabstrip">
            <div id="tabstrip">
                <ul>
                    <li class="k-state-active">Option1</li>
                    <li>Option2</li>
                    <li>Option3</li>
                    <li>Option4</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="frame_top">
            <h2 class="contentTitle">&nbsp;text here&nbsp;<small>text here</small></h2>
            <div id="chartSummary">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="frame_bottom">
            <h2 class="contentTitle">&nbsp;text here&nbsp;<small>text here</small></h2>
            <div class="summary_bar">
                <div class="summary_title">
                    <div id="Top1Author">
                    </div>
                    <div id="Top1Tags">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="summary_bullet">
                    <div id="chartTop1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="summary_area">
                    <div id="areaTop1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="summary_value">
                    <div id="Top1UservsTotal" style="text-align:center">
                    </div>
                    <div id="Top1UservsTotal_Desc" style="text-align:center">
                        <p class="tag_text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="summary_bar">
                <div class="summary_title">
                    <div id="Top2Author">
                    </div>
                    <div id="Top2Tags">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="summary_bullet">
                    <div id="chartTop2">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="summary_area">
                    <div id="areaTop2">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="summary_value">
                    <div id="Top2UservsTotal" style="text-align:center">
                    </div>
                    <div id="Top2UservsTotal_Desc" style="text-align:center">
                        <p class="tag_text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="summary_bar">
                <div class="summary_title">
                    <div id="Top3Author">
                    </div>
                    <div id="Top3Tags">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="summary_bullet">
                    <div id="chartTop3">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="summary_area">
                    <div id="areaTop3">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="summary_value">
                    <div id="Top3UservsTotal" style="text-align:center">
                    </div>
                    <div id="Top3UservsTotal_Desc" style="text-align:center">
                        <p class="tag_text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Found the issue. I'd used jsonpCallback: "JsonPCallBack" on each datasource. Editing each callback to have a unique name fixed the problem (new it would be something silly).

Answer (score 0):

Unique JsonPCallback values were the fix for this.